# Batch to kill a process either by PID or process name, depending on user input

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to create a batch file to kill a process either by id or by name depending on the user's choice. For example if he chooses `1`, then he is promoted to enter the pid and then the code executes the command `taskkill /PID processNumber /F`,  if he selects `2`, he enters the process name and the code executes `taskkill /IM processName.exe /F`

My issue is that the code always enters a loop after entering either the pid or name.

Here's my code:

```
@echo off
title TASKKILL
tasklist
echo _____________________________________________________________
echo Press 1 to choose PID
echo Press 2 to choose Process Name
set /p option=
if %option% == 1 goto id
if %option% == 2 goto proc
goto out
:id
set /p pid="Enter the PID of the process you want to kill: "
echo %pid%
taskkill /PID %pid% /F
:proc
set /p processName="Enter the name of the process you want to kill: "
echo %processName%
taskkill /IM %processName%.exe /F
pause
```

Comment: Where is label `:out`? Anyway, you need to control where execution continues after each section `:id`, `:proc`; otherwise it just continues at the next line. And take a look at [`choice`](http://sa64.com/nt/choice.html)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off
title TASKKILL
tasklist
echo _____________________________________________________________
echo Press 1 to choose PID
echo Press 2 to choose Process Name
set /p option=
if "%option%"=="1" goto :id
if "%option%"=="2" goto :proc

goto :out
:id
set /p pid="Enter the PID of the process you want to kill: "
echo %pid%
taskkill /PID %pid% /F

goto :out
:proc
set /p processName="Enter the name of the process you want to kill: "
echo %processName%
taskkill /IM %processName%.exe /F

:out
pause
```

You need to avoid the *functions* in the normal flow, by putting `goto :eof` or `goto :outbranch` before them.

So my change here was to add the `:out` label, and add `goto :out` before those two *functions*.

Note when using `if` to check variable's value, it's better to quote both the variable and the value you are checking, and leave no spaces before and after `==`, like this:

```
if "%var%"=="value" echo "It's euqal!"
```

So I changed the `if %option% == 1` part :)

Comment: Same code copy paste. I'm not combining it with another code

Comment: I restarted my laptop and re-executed the batch file, it worked. Didn't change anything. Thank you! I'll mark it as answer